# Не срабатывает @ExceptionHandler при валидации null полей в json запросе

Tags: java, spring, валидация, exception-handler, javax

Есть body

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RegistryRequest implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @NotNull @Size(min=1)
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;

    @JsonProperty("count")
    @NotNull @Size(min=1)
    private String count;

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    @NotNull @Size(min=1)
    private String amount;

    @JsonProperty("payments")
    private PaymentModel[] payments;

}
```

метод для отлавливания ошибки

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

почему то не срабатывает когда посылаю запрос без одного из полей.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class RfController implements RegistryFacadeApi {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registryTransfer(@Valid RegistryRequest registry)
```

---

контракт

```
@PostMapping(BASEPATH,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    ResponseEntity<Object> registryTransfer(
            @RequestBody @Valid RegistryRequest registry)
```

Comment: А вы покажите ещё контроллер свой и хэндлер полностью ну или верхушку хотя бы. И аннотирован ли у вас хэндлер как @RestControllerAdvice или @ControllerAdvice? И ещё, разве методы перехватчика не должны принимать ещё HttpServletRequest помимо ошибки?

Comment: Да, кстати, вы подключили собственно сам валидатор в конфиге?

Comment: добавил в впорос аннотации над контроллером. да @ControllerAdvice указан на классом хендлера. разве методы перехватчика не должны принимать ещё HttpServletRequest помимо ошибки попробовал с ним но не прошло.  подключили собственно сам валидатор в конфиге -нет. я так понимаю он сам настраивается пристарте spring

Comment: нужно было @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) отлавливать

Comment: странно. По-моему Exception.class должен был всё перехватывать. Ну если других методов нет, конечно.